# How to fix unsaved transient instance during unit testing

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-data-jpa, mockito, h2

I want to write some tests to find an object by some given attibute; but before that i want to make use of the setUp method to initialize the object i want to test for. but this object is also dependent on another object which i want to create as a mock, but i cant call the method the test methid as it throws this exception: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing.
This is the sample code below, please tell me what am missing and how to make it better, thanks.

```
@DataJpaTest(properties = {
                "spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none"
        })
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class EmailVerificationTokenRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private EmailVerificationTokenRepository repository;

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    /**
     * Test of findByToken method, of class EmailVerificationTokenRepository.
     */
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        Set role = new HashSet<>();
        role.add("ROLE_USER");
        Users expected = Users.builder()
                .id(null)
                .email("david@gmail.com")
                .password("1234")
                .isEnabled(true)
                .isNonLocked(true)
                .roles(role)
                .createdAt(LocalDateTime.now())
                .build();               
        Mockito.when(userRepository.save(expected)).thenReturn(expected);
        Users actual = userRepository.save(expected);
        System.out.println(actual);
        EmailVerificationToken evt = EmailVerificationToken.builder()
                .createdAt(LocalDateTime.now())
                .expiresAt(LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(4))
                .token("token")
                .user(actual)
                .build();
        repository.save(evt);
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() {
        repository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Test to find Email Verification Object By Token")
    public void testFindByToken() {
        String token = "token";
        Optional<EmailVerificationToken> result = repository.findByToken(token);
        assertTrue(result.isPresent());
    }

    /**
     * Test of findByUser method, of class EmailVerificationTokenRepository.
     */
    @Test
    @Disabled
    @DisplayName("Test to find Email Verification Object By User")
    public void testFindByUser() {
        //Given
        Set role = new HashSet<>();
        role.add("ROLE_USER");
        Users user = Users.builder()
                .id(null)
                .email("david@gmail.com")
                .password("1234")
                .isEnabled(true)
                .isNonLocked(true)
                .roles(role)
                .createdAt(LocalDateTime.now())
                .build();
        Optional<EmailVerificationToken> result = repository.findByUser(user);
        assertTrue(result.isPresent());
    }

}
```

And these are my logs:

```
2023-02-26 18:57:11.507  INFO [,,] 12780 --- [           main] u.r.EmailVerificationTokenRepositoryTest : Started EmailVerificationTokenRepositoryTest in 7.485 seconds (JVM running for 11.929)
2023-02-26 18:57:11.588  INFO [,,] 12780 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@2b76ff4e testClass = EmailVerificationTokenRepositoryTest, testInstance = com.slinkdigital.user.repository.EmailVerificationTokenRepositoryTest@73eae5f, testMethod = testFindByToken@EmailVerificationTokenRepositoryTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@7a1234bf testClass = EmailVerificationTokenRepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.slinkdigital.user.UserApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@2f62ea70 key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6f3187b0, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@189cbd7c, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@723e88f9, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@6ea2bc93, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@474abc3a, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@48c76607, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@0], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false, 'org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.mocks' -> org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine$$Lambda$406/0x0000000800e49720@4902c584]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@42ef5216]; rollback [true]
Users(id=null, email=david@gmail.com, password=1234, createdAt=2023-02-26T18:57:11.641991300, isNonLocked=false, isEnabled=false, roles=[ROLE_USER])
2023-02-26 18:57:11.774 DEBUG [,,] 12780 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    insert 
    into
        email_verification_token
        (id, created_at, expires_at, token, user_id) 
    values
        (default, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        email_verification_token
        (id, created_at, expires_at, token, user_id) 
    values
        (default, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2023-02-26 18:57:12.033  INFO [,,] 12780 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@2b76ff4e testClass = EmailVerificationTokenRepositoryTest, testInstance = com.slinkdigital.user.repository.EmailVerificationTokenRepositoryTest@73eae5f, testMethod = testFindByToken@EmailVerificationTokenRepositoryTest, testException = org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.slinkdigital.user.domain.EmailVerificationToken.user -> com.slinkdigital.user.domain.Users; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.slinkdigital.user.domain.EmailVerificationToken.user -> com.slinkdigital.user.domain.Users, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@7a1234bf testClass = EmailVerificationTokenRepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.slinkdigital.user.UserApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@2f62ea70 key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6f3187b0, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@189cbd7c, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@723e88f9, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@6ea2bc93, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@474abc3a, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@48c76607, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@0], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false, 'org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.mocks' -> org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine$$Lambda$406/0x0000000800e49720@4902c584]]
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 10.605 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.slinkdigital.user.repository.EmailVerificationTokenRepositoryTest
testFindByToken  Time elapsed: 0.024 s  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.slinkdigital.user.domain.EmailVerificationToken.user -> com.slinkdigital.user.domain.Users; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.slinkdigital.user.domain.EmailVerificationToken.user -> com.slinkdigital.user.domain.Users
    at com.slinkdigital.user.repository.EmailVerificationTokenRepositoryTest.testFindByToken(EmailVerificationTokenRepositoryTest.java:76)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.slinkdigital.user.domain.EmailVerificationToken.user -> com.slinkdigital.user.domain.Users
    at com.slinkdigital.user.repository.EmailVerificationTokenRepositoryTest.testFindByToken(EmailVerificationTokenRepositoryTest.java:76)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.slinkdigital.user.domain.EmailVerificationToken.user -> com.slinkdigital.user.domain.Users
    at com.slinkdigital.user.repository.EmailVerificationTokenRepositoryTest.testFindByToken(EmailVerificationTokenRepositoryTest.java:76)
```

I will appreciate every assistance i can get, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object
> references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance
> before flushing :
> **com.slinkdigital.user.domain.EmailVerificationToken.user ->**
> **com.slinkdigital.user.domain.Users**

The error message already gives you some hint. It is because the user of the `EmailVerificationToken` that you create is not managed by JPA . Because you create it using a mocked `UserRepository` which is fake. So from JPA 's point of view , this user instance never exist.

You must create the user or get an existing user by the **actual** `UserRepository` but not the **mocked** one. There is no other choice. Why do you want to use the mocked `UserRepository` rather than the actual one ?

So change to the following should fix the problem:

```java
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;
```

Comment: oh, thanks for the response, i know for sure it  would work if i use an actual instance of the UserRepository, but just started learning mocking and i thought there would be a way to get it to work, seems not every component dependendent on another component should be mocked, thanks

Comment: yes. it depends on the usecase which in this case definitely not suitable to use it.